# How do I get a div just as high as the one right to it

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of list elements and in there I have 2 div's floating left. I want that when the sencond div gets more content that the div left to it automaticly gets the same height.

I have both divs in a different bg color so when 1 has less content then the other, the div gets higher and the bg dont match horizontaly.

Maby you could take a quick peek at the website, then you know exactly what I mean,
http://newsbreak.vazcreations.nl (top middle container is the problem).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved reasonably easily without javascript. It's recommended that you don't use javascript to achieve something if it's avoidable as not all users have javascript enabled.

The technique that is employed to solve your problem, without using javascript, is called [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) (this article goes one step further and uses images, but you don't need to.

Essentially you place the div on the right **inside** the left div. Set the width of the left div to the ideal total width of both divs, and then float the right div to the right. You may need to apply a [clearfix](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) to the left div so that is properly wraps around the second div.

**Edit:** I've just come across [an article](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61) which proposes a few other solutions which seem to be worth looking into.

Comment: Oke, I guess your solution is the best, thanks. But I don't know if its me or that it does not work.

Comment: What's the problem that you're encountering with getting it working?

Comment: I'm new to the clearfix so dont know how that works. And should I then rewrite my code or can I keep using the curent? I now use li as a parent.

Comment: This demonstrates the changes that you need to make to your HTML & CSS: http://pastebin.com/Nv0PZqXH

Comment: And with regards to the clearfix, it is to overcome the issue that occurs when children of a parent element are floated and as a result the parent element 'collapses'. It's important that you read up on the behaviour of floats and why clearfixes are necessary, but for now try adding "overflow: hidden;" to the css properties of the class: main-date-background.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help. If you would check the link in my description you see it worked. Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work:

**EDIT**: This is probably a better solution

```
<style type="text/css">   
#container {    
    display:table;    
    border-collapse:collapse;    
}         
#layout {    
    display:table-row;    
}           
#left-sidebar, #right-sidebar, #content {    
    text-align:left; 
    display:table-cell;    
}           
</style>   

<div id="container">    
    <div id="layout">    
        <div id="left-sidebar">    
            <!-- left sidebar--> 
        </div>    
        <div id="content"> 
            <!-- content --> 
        </div> 
        <div id="right-sidebar">    
            <!-- right sidebar -->    
        </div>    
    </div>   
</div>
```

See this jsFiddle for a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/Qhk7R/

Comment: Oke thanks dude, I will now try this on my design. Just have figure this out how to get it on my coding.

Answer (score 0):

You could fake it with changing this:

```
.recent-item {
    height: 50px;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
```

to

```
.recent-item {
    height: 50px;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    background-color: #CDCDCD;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

and removing the top margin for .main-date and .recent-bericht

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery:

```
var div_1_height = $('.div-1').height();
$('.div-2).height(div_1_height);
```

Comment: Javascript should be a last resort; there is a range of solutions to this problem that can be employed, instead of using javascript.